# Time.sleep() function doesn't seem to work properly while threading

Tags: python

I am creating a monke game and I want the hunger variable to decrease by 1.5/10s. I used threads for that and the time.sleep() function didn't seem to work. It works when you start the program and wait for 10 seconds but then it starts decreasing rapidly without the other time.sleep() functions. I have a loop in a thread so the hunger would decrease in a loop.

I'm using Windows 11 and using VS Code IDE, if it matters.
It worked for someone I asked help from on a Discord server but I still don't get what the problem could be here.

The thread is at the start of the code so no need to scroll all down looking for it.

```
# Modules:
import random, time, threading
# Define the variables:

# Supplies:
animalskilled = 0
leather = 0
leaves = 0

wood = 0
metal = 0
stone = 0
bones = 0

strings = 0
# Weapon variables:
spear = 0
sword = 0
axe = 1
daggers = 0
bow = 0
pickaxes = 1

# Food variables:
meat = 0

# Other:
fires = 0
health = 100
hunger = 100

print("You are a monke. What would you like to do?")
# Define main function:
def main():
    # Globalize variables:
    global health
    global fires
    global meat
    global spear
    global sword
    global bow
    global axe
    global daggers
    global pickaxes
    global animalskilled
    global strings
    global wood
    global stone
    global metal
    global bones
    global leather
    global leaves

    def hungerloss():
        global hunger
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
            hunger -= 1.5
    x = threading.Thread(target=hungerloss)
    x.start()
    # Print out health and hunger status:
    print(f'Health: {health}')
    print(f'Hunger: {hunger}')
    print()
    print('1. Start a fire (you can also extinguish it)')
    print('2. Craft something')
    print('3. Hunt down animals')
    print('4. Get supplies')
    # Input field:
    entry = input('>>> ').lower()

    # If input is start a fire:
    if entry in ('1.', '1', 'start a fire'):
        # If user has started 0 fires:
        if fires == 0:
            # If user doesn't have 8 wood or 4 leaves:
            if wood < 8 or leaves < 4:
                print('You need 8 wood and 4 leaves to start a fire!')
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 3)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else if user has 8 wood and 4 leaves:
            else:
                print('You have started a fire.')
                # Remove 8 from wood variable:
                wood -= 8
                # Remove 4 from leaves variable:
                leaves -= 4
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 3)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
        # Else if user has already started a fire:
        else:
            print('You already have a fire burning! Extinguishing current one.')
            # Remove 1 from fires variable:
            fires -= 1
            # Wait for 3 seconds:
            time.sleep(3)
            print('\n' * 3)
            # Call the main function:
            main()

        
    # Else if input is craft something:
    elif entry in ('2.', '2', 'craft something'):
        print('\n' * 3)
        print('1. Spear')
        print('2. Sword')
        print('3. Axe')
        print('4. Daggers')
        print('5. Bow')
        # Input field:
        craftentry = input('What would you like to craft?: ').lower()
        # If user wants to craft a spear:
        if craftentry in ('1.', '1', 'spear'):
            # If user doesn't have 3 wood:
            if wood < 3:
                print('You need wood to craft a spear!')
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else if user has 3 wood:
            else:
                # Input field:
                confirm = input('Craft a spear out of 3 wood? (Y/N): ').lower()
                # If user doesn't want to craft a spear:
                if confirm not in 'y':
                    # Wait for 3 seconds:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print('\n' * 5)
                    # Call the main function:
                    main()
                # Else if the user wants to craft a spear:
                else:
                    print('You have crafted a spear.')
                    # Remove 3 from wood variable:
                    wood -= 3
                    # Add 1 to spear variable:
                    spear += 1
                    # Wait for 3 seconds:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print('\n' * 5)
                    # Call the main function:
                    main()

        # Elif user wants to craft a sword:
        elif craftentry in ('2.', '2', 'sword'):
            # If user already has a sword:
            if sword >= 1:
                print('You already have a sword!')
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 3)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else if the user doesn't have a sword:
            else:
                # If user doesn't have 5 metal:
                if metal < 5:
                    print('You need 5 metal to craft a sword!')
                    # Wait for 3 seconds:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print('\n' * 3)
                    # Call the main function:
                    main()
                # Else if the user has 5 metal:
                else:
                    # Input field:
                    confirm = input('Craft a sword with 5 metal? (Y/N):').lower()
                    # If user doesn't want to craft a sword:
                    if confirm not in 'y':
                        # Wait for 3 seconds:
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('\n' * 5)
                        # Call the main function:
                        main()
                    # Else if the user wants to craft a sword:
                    else:
                        print('You have crafted a sword.')
                        # Add 1 to sword variable:
                        sword += 1
                        # Remove 5 from metal variable:
                        metal -= 5
                        # Wait for 3 seconds:
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('\n' * 5)
                        # Call the main function:
                        main()

        # Else if the user wants to craft an axe:
        elif craftentry in ('3.', '3', 'axe'):
            # If user already has an axe:
            if axe >= 1:
                print('You already have an axe!')
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 3)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else if the user doesn't have an axe:
            else:
                # If user doesn't have 6 wood:
                if wood < 6:
                    print('You need 6 wood to craft an axe!')
                    # Wait for 3 seconds:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print('\n' * 3)
                    # Call the main function:
                    main()
                # Else if the user has 6 wood:
                else:
                    # Input field:
                    confirm = input('Craft an axe with 6 wood? (Y/N):').lower()
                    # If the user doesn't want to craft an axe:
                    if confirm not in 'y':
                        # Wait for 3 seconds:
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('\n' * 5)
                        # Call the main function:
                        main()
                    # Else if the user wants to craft an axe:
                    else:
                        print('You have crafted an axe.')
                        # Add 1 to axe variable:
                        axe += 1
                        # Remove 6 from wood variable:
                        wood -= 6
                        # Wait for 3 seconds:
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('\n' * 5)
                        # Call the main function:
                        main()

        # Else if the user wants to craft daggers:
        elif craftentry in ('4.', '4', 'daggers'):
            # If the user already has daggers:
            if daggers >= 1:
                print('You already have daggers!')
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 3)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else if the user doesn't have daggers:
            else:
                # If user doesn't have 3 metal or 2 bones:
                if metal < 3 or bones < 2:
                    print('You need 3 metal and 2 bones to craft daggers!')
                    # Wait for 3 seconds:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print('\n' * 3)
                    # Call the main function:
                    main()
                # Else if the user has 3 metal and 2 bones:
                else:
                    # Input field:
                    confirm = input('Craft daggers with 3 metal and 2 bones? (Y/N):').lower()
                    # If user doesn't want to craft daggers:
                    if confirm not in 'y':
                        # Wait for 3 seconds:
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('\n' * 5)
                        # Call the main function:
                        main()
                    # Else if the user wants to craft daggers:
                    else:
                        print('You have crafted daggers.')
                        # Add 1 to daggers variable:
                        daggers += 1
                        # Remove 1 from metal variable:
                        metal -= 3
                        # Remove 1 from bones variable:
                        bones -= 2
                        # Wait for 3 seconds:
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('\n' * 5)
                        # Call the main function:
                        main()

        # Elif user wants to craft a bow:
        elif craftentry in ('5.', '5', 'bow'):
            # If user already has a bow:
            if bow >= 1:
                print('You already have a bow!')
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 3)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else if the user doesn't have a bow:
            else:
                # If user doesn't have 3 wood or 2 strings:
                if wood < 3 or strings < 2:
                    print('You need 3 wood and 2 strings to craft a bow!')
                    # Wait for 3 seconds:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print('\n' * 3)
                    # Call the main function:
                    main()
                # Else if the user has 3 wood and 2 strings:
                else:
                    # Input field:
                    confirm = input('Craft a bow with 3 wood and 2 strings? (Y/N):').lower()
                    # If the user doesn't want to craft a bow:
                    if confirm not in 'y':
                        # Wait for 3 seconds:
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('\n' * 5)
                        # Call the main function:
                        main()
                    # Else if the user wants to craft a bow:
                    else:
                        print('You have crafted a bow.')
                        # Add 1 to bow variable:
                        bow += 1
                        # Remove 3 from wood variable:
                        wood -= 3
                        # Remove 2 from strings variable:
                        strings -= 2
                        # Wait for 3 seconds:
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('\n' * 5)
                        # Call the main function:
                        main()

    # Else if entry is hunt down animals:
    elif entry in ('3.', '3', 'hunt down animals'):
        print('\n' * 3)
        # Input field:
        confirm = input('Hunt down an animal? (Y/N): ').lower()
        # If user doesn't want to hunt down animals:
        if confirm not in 'Y':
            # Wait for 3 seconds:
            time.sleep(3)
            print('\n' * 5)
            # Call the main function:
            main()
        # Else if the user wants to hunt down animals:
        else:
            # Variables that contain the random func.:
            animalchoice = random.choice('cow', 'sheep', 'pig', 'chicken', 'lion', 'nothing')
            healthlost = random.randrange(1, 30)
            meatgained = random.randrange(1, 10)
            leathergained = random.randrange(1, 5)
            # Else if user didn't get to hunt down any animals:
            if animalchoice == 'nothing':
                print(f"You didn't find any animals to hunt!")
                # Wait for 4 seconds:
                time.sleep(4)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else:
            else:
                print(f'You put down a {animalchoice}! You gained {meatgained} meat, {leathergained} leather and lost {healthlost} health.')
                # Add 1 to animalskilled variable:
                animalskilled += 1
                # Add (meatgained) to meat variable:
                meat += meatgained
                leather += leathergained
                # Remove (healthlost) from health variable:
                health -= healthlost
                # Wait for 4 seconds:
                time.sleep(4)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()


    elif entry in ('4', '4.', 'get supplies'):
        print('Materials: \n\n')
        print('1. Trees')
        print('2. Stone')
        print('3. Metal')
        print('4. String')
        # Input field:
        supplyentry = input('What would you like to harvest?: ').lower()
        # If user wants to take down trees:
        if supplyentry in ('1.', '1', 'trees'):
            # Define variables:
            woodamount = random.randrange(0,10)
            leavesamount = random.randrange(0,4)
            # If user didn't find any trees: 
            if woodamount == 0:
                print("You didn't find any trees!")
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else if the user found trees:
            else:
                print(f'You brought trees down with an axe and got {woodamount} wood and {leavesamount} leaves!')
                # Add (woodamount) to wood variable:
                wood += woodamount
                # Add (leaves) to leavesamount variable:
                leaves += leavesamount
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()

        # Else if user wants to obtain stone:
        elif supplyentry in ('2.', '2', 'stone'):
            # Define the variable:
            stoneamount = random.randrange(0,7)
            # If user didn't get to obtain any stone:
            if stoneamount == 0:
                print("You didn't get to obtain any stone!")
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else if the user got to obtain stone:
            else:
                print(f'You obtained {stoneamount} stone!')
                # Add (stoneamount) to stone variable
                stone += stoneamount
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()

        # Else if the user wants to obtain metal:
        elif supplyentry in ('3', '3.', 'metal'):
            # Define variable:
            metalamount = random.randrange(0,5)
            # If user didn't find any metal:
            if metalamount == 0:
                print("You didn't find any metal from mining!")
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else if the user found metal:
            else:
                print(f'You mined and got {metalamount} metal!')
                # Add (metalamount) to metal variable:
                metal += metalamount
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            
        # Else if the user wants to obtain string:
        elif supplyentry in ('4', '4.', 'string'):
            # Define variable:
            stringamount = random.randrange(0,3)
            # If user didn't find any strings:
            if stringamount == 0:
                print("You didn't find any strings!")
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()
            # Else if the user found strings:
            else:
                print(f'You found cobwebs and got {stringamount} strings!')
                # Add (stringamount) to strings variable:
                strings += stringamount
                # Wait for 3 seconds:
                time.sleep(3)
                print('\n' * 5)
                # Call the main function:
                main()

    # Else if the user typed in something else out of choices:
    else:
        print('\n' * 30)
        # Call the main function:
        main()

# Call the main function:
main()
```

Comment: Please read [mre]

Comment: That's a lot of code. It helps to write a separate _minimal_ script that demonstrates the problem without all the other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the others are talking about, this really isn't that much to handle. You even mentioned that the most essential part is right at the top.

The problem is actually quite simple: you create the thread inside `main()`, but you call `main()` recursively, so you're actually creating *multiple threads*, each with their own timers, none of which can stop on their own. The longer you play, the more `hungerloss()` threads are created, and thus the more timers are started. If you want, you can visualize this by saving a random number to the top of `hungerloss()` and printing it out every time the sleep timer finishes.

All you need to do is avoid recreating the same thread multiple times. The simplest way considering the structure of your current code would probably be to just move `hungerloss()` outside of `main()`, like so:

```
def hungerloss():
    global hunger
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        hunger -= 1.5

threading.Thread(target=hungerloss).start()

def main():
    # you get the idea
```

Comment: Well that was a simple fix.. Thanks a lot!